# set height of all uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

i am using master-detail view and a simple-view page, all of which are having their own `UINavigationController`. I wish to have same background image for all the `UINavigationControllers` so i use the following line of code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This solves my purpose but the height of the uiNavigationBar is more so that it overlaps the content below. 
How do i reduce the navigationController's height?

Answer (score 0):

Apply following to the UIView you would like to adjust (position and size):

```
[UIView setFrame:CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)]
```

Comment: isnt there a way to reduce the height of uinavigationController?